# Carregar registro pelo ID no Angular

Tags: angular

**Essa abaixo é uma breve explicação.**

Ao clicar no registro em tela navegador não consigo carregar os registros de acordo com o ID.

**Esse abaixo é uma aplicação detalhada;**

Veja o arquivo gif

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você pode perceber que existem dois registros sendo carregados e ao clicar nos registros ele consegue carregar na URL o ID do registro, ao visualizar o console você percebe que ele lista os registros do banco que são somente dois mesmo.

O problema é que ao colocar na página `{{ restaurant?.name }}` ele não imprime na tela o valor do banco.

Não sei o que estou fazendo de errado, essa é minha classe de serviços;

```
 restaurantById(id: string): Observable<Restaurant> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.url}/restaurants/${name}`)
    .map(response =>  response.json().restaurants)
    .catch(ErrorHandler.handlerError)
  }
```

Essa é minha classe do componente de acordo com pagina web.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.restaurantService.restaurantById(this.route.snapshot.params['id'])
    .subscribe(restaurant =>  this.restaurant = restaurant)
}
```

[ESSE É MEU REPOSITÓRIO](https://github.com/wladyband/restaurant_MEAN/tree/master/src/app/restaurant)

desculpe ter colocado em caixa alta, porque as vezes as pessoas não percebem que tenho colocado o link do meu repositório.

A pagina está dentro do pacote **restaurant-detail** e o serviço é o arquivo **restaurant.service.ts**

Estarei esperando um retorno, preciso muito de ajuda.

REPOSTA DO SERVIDOR

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não deveria ser `${id}` aqui?? `this.http.get(`${this.url}/restaurants/${name}`

Comment: Se eu colocar o como está sugerindo ele não carrega os registro do banco na classe de componentes

Comment: Mas aí tem que ver o retorno da API tbm, e ajustar conforme necessário... O que está acontecendo é que você provavelmente está recebendo um array de restaurantes (vide `response.json().restaurants`), mas tenta exibir um só.

Comment: Na sua classe de serviço onde tem `.map(response =>  response.json().restaurants)` não deveria ser? `.map(response =>  response.json())`

Comment: @Marconi eu tentei sua sugestão, mas não pegou, ainda não está aparecendo os registros em tela.

Comment: @wladyband você iniciou o json-server?

Comment: Tenta assim: `restaurantById(id: string): Observable<Restaurant> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.url}/restaurants/${id}`)
    .map(response =>  response.json())
    .catch(ErrorHandler.handlerError)`
  }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu método `restaurantById` está ignorando o parâmetro `id`, e usando uma variável que não existe (`name`). Desta forma ele vai fazer a requisição em `/restaurants/` e listar todos os restaurantes.

Isto fica evidenciado pela necessidade de usar o `.restaurants` no método map:

```
restaurantById(id: string): Observable<Restaurant> {
  return this.http.get(`${this.url}/restaurants/${name}`)
  .map(response =>  response.json().restaurants)
  .catch(ErrorHandler.handlerError)
}
```

De acordo com a resposta do servidor postada, a implementação ideal seria:

```
restaurantById(id: string): Observable<Restaurant> {
  return this.http.get(`${this.url}/restaurants/${id}`)
  .map(response =>  response.json().restaurant)
  .catch(ErrorHandler.handlerError)
}
```

Comment: Deu para ajudar em partes, porque agora ele não carrega no console do navegador todos os registros ele carrega somente aquele que foi clicado, porém quando coloco  {{ restaurants?.name}} não parece o registro em tela.

Comment: Tem como mostrar como está vindo a resposta do servidor?

Comment: acabei de atualizar a postagem, veja já por favor

Comment: @wladyband atualizei a reposta com o mapeamento necessário.

Comment: funcionou, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta assim:

Service

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

restaurantById(id: string): Observable<Restaurant> {
  return this.http.get<Restaurant>(`${this.url}/restaurants/${id}`)
  .pipe(map(response =>  response.restaurant),
       catchError(ErrorHandler.handlerError)
  )      
}
```

Component

```
constructor(protected route: ActivatedRoute)

this.route.params.pipe(
        map(params => params['id']),
        switchMap(id=> this.restaurantService.restaurantById(id))
       .subscribe(restaurant => this.restaurant = restaurant );
```

Comment: poderia por favor me dizer as importações para as variaveis "map", "switchMap" e "params" ?

Comment: está gerando essa mensagem de erro:

TypeError: operators_1.switchMap(...).subscribe is not a function
    at RestaurantDetailComponent.ngOnInit (restaurant-detail.component.ts:28)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:12411)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:13935)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:13878)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:14771)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:14712)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (RestaurantDetailComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:14697)

Comment: Estou usando o rxjs 6 se vc esta usando o 5 são os mesmos operadores, so muda imports e invés de colocar dentro do pipe vc chama com .map inves de pipe(map)

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo esforço de está tentando me ajuda, sou muito grato.

Comment: Presta atenção que no seu serviço vc esta chamando response.restaurants